# Allow insertion only if count is less than 10

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

My database name is *registration*. In that I need to validate 2 conditions.

1. `where status="checked"`
2. `status count is <10`

I can insert data. Otherwise it displays some alert msg

Here is my code:

```
<?php
class Profile extends CI_Model{
   function add($data){
      $this->load->database();
      $count1="select count(status) from registration where status='checked'";
      $this->db->where($count1<10);
      $this->db->insert('registration',$data);
   }
```

Comment: Invalid edit by crafter! please check before editing. There wasn't need of removing tag `codeigniter` and Also I don't know `how you say this as a formatting edit?`

Comment: I did a rollback to yours @Log1c

Comment: ok, good. I tried but don't know why It wasn't rollback. Is there any special privileges needed for that?

Comment: I do believe so. @Log1c

Comment: So the only time you will add the data, if there are less than 10 entries that have status='checked'? Am i right?

Comment: Enough with the edits already. Minimum, at best.

Comment: Why all of you write  ->where($count1<10) ???  this will PHP lead to compair the sql-Query-Text $count1 with 10 -> so it will be FALSE every time! 1.) you need to execute the Query(count1), 2.) you need to read the result and compair the result!

Answer (score 2):

I need some more information to solve your problem.

And you can use log.message('info', print_r($data, true)); to debug the code.

Before that you should set log threshold as 4 and log file path.
You can see the log file to check till where your code is executing and values are passing or not.

```
class Profile extends CI_Model{

   function add($data){
      $this->load->database();
      $count1="select count(status) from registration where status='checked'";
      if(count1 < 10) {
          $this->db->insert('registration',$data);
      } else {
          return false;

   }
```

Use that false value to show alert.

Comment: i try this code using kate.where i can use log.message

Comment: In model or controller, anywhere you wish to check

Comment: i dontknow how to debug the code bcz i am writing code in kate editor

Comment: Dnt worry abt the editor. Just put log.message("info", "Your message"); in any controller or any model, before that set the log threshold as 4 and log path in config.php,then run the program. You'll get a file created with date. In that file u can see "Your message". Instead of this message you can use any variable to see its value

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK You can´t do this with your aggregation query. Launch the query and, by code, check the count

```
 if ( data < 10 ){
    ...
 } else {
    ...
 }
```

Other option is make a SQL function.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

There must be no more than 10 "checked" registration records? What you do is okay so far then. You get the count from the db and only insert when the count is less than 10. But this check doesn't have to be done in the db. Simply trigger the insert only when count < 10:

```
<?php
  class Profile extends CI_Model{function add($data)
  {
    $this->load->database();
    $count1="select count(*) from registration where status = 'checked'";
    if($count1 < 10)
    {
      $this->db->insert('registration', $data);
    }
  }
```

That's it more or less. I don't use php regularly, so there might still be errors in this. Do you need an explicit commit? I don't know.